# How to get DeviceId for new enrolled Android devices inside EMM through Android Management APIs without pubsub?

Tags: android-management-api

Want deviceId for enrolled devices through AMA API. Enrolling group of devices through same token id.  How do we get deviceId's?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [enterprises.devices.list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list) to get the list of devices for a given enterprise. It returns a JSON of device resources that contains the **deviceID**.

The **deviceID** can be found in the `name` field of the device resource.
E.g. 
 `name: enterprises/{enterpriseId}/devices/{deviceId}`

**Sample JSON response**:

```
{
  "name": "enterprises/LCqwe1231/devices/123qwe1231",
  "managementMode": "DEVICE_OWNER",
  "state": "ACTIVE",
  "appliedState": "ACTIVE",
  "policyCompliant": true,
}
```

> **Note**: The previous **DeviceIDs** enrolled are still in the enterprise. If you get a list of **DeviceIDs**, get the ID that is in the uppermost part of the list. If you want to delete previous devices, you can use [enterprises.devices.delete](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete).